# Ubuntu 23.10 is now on-topic!

Tags: discussion

Ubuntu 23.10 (https://releases.ubuntu.com/mantic) is now released and is on topic.

As usual, posts still must meet [the normal requirements for being on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), though.

Additionally, please refrain from re-opening questions about Ubuntu 23.10 that were posted prior to its release without Meta consensus. They can be re-opened, but it needs to be agreed upon via a Meta discussion first.

---

<s>Note: some of the images [were un-released](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/announcement-ubuntu-desktop-23-10-release-image-is-being-updated-to-resolve-a-malicious-translation-incident/39365) as a result of malicious/offensive translations.</s>

Comment: To the downvoter: Is there something I could improve with this post…?

Answer (score 12):

Ubuntu 23.10 has a new default software center which is called the App Center.
The new App Center has been written from the ground up to be more efficient and reliable.

Here is the [app-center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/app-center) tag. Questions about the App Center are on topic at Ask Ubuntu.

Here is the [23.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/23.10) tag.

Comment: If you upgraded from an older version of Ubuntu, you may not see the "App Center" app, only "Ubuntu Software". This is a bug, [solved here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1488852/2355). I was confused by this at first.

Comment: @Flimm I'm already familiar with that excellent linked question, and I upvoted both the question and its accepted answer.